# Repair FAT filesystem on image

Tags: filesystems, fsck, dd, fat32

I've got a USB pen drive with a corrupted FAT filesystem. Now I try to repair it. So to first try what I can get from it without endangering the original hardware further, I've created an image with `dd` using the following command line:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=pendrive.img
```

Now I want to repair the filesystem in the image by running `fsck`.

But `fsck` immediately terminates as follows:

```
$ sudo fsck.vfat -a -t -v pendrive.img
fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
Logical sector size is zero.
```

Is there any trick how I can tell `fsck` to assume a sector size or what does this message mean? Can somebody help interpreting this output?

This question is similar to [fsck a filesystem in a file](https://serverfault.com/questions/398109/fsck-a-filesystem-in-a-file) but this was about ext2.
Also https://superuser.com/questions/129189/cant-mount-fat32-drive-under-ubuntu-linux gave no answer.

Comment: What was the exact command line you used to make the image?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I've added the info the the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made the image of your whole USB pen drive with your `dd` command. This means that the image includes also a partition table.

That is why you cannot mount the image directly as a file system.

To mount the filesystem inside the image, you need to use `kpartx` utility to generate virtual devices from the partition table in your image.

```
kpartx -v -a /path/to/image
```

will create new partition mappings inside your `/dev/mapper` directory, which will point to the actual partitions inside your image. Then you can use these entries as the device for `mount` command or for `fsck.vfat` command.

Comment: 8-| sure I was aware of this, wen I selected the dev file, but not now, that I started `fsck` :-D thx

Comment: Funny, I can mojnt the filesystem using `sudo mount -o loop /path/to.img /mnt` and read the files without a problem.

Comment: This works when the device doesn't have a partition table and all the device space is used for the filesystem itself.